# C# square split

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, drawing

I'm doing this out of pure curiosity and I've been trying to do this for days but I seem to be stuck.

I'm trying to do the following:

[image: For this I'm using buttons and the "click" event]

for the moment, I'm trying just to get one of the squares to infinitely split every time I click on it. 
Here's the code I'm working on:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace divideSquare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button centerSquare = new Button();
        private Button topLeftSquare = new Button();
        private Button topRightSquare = new Button();
        private Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
        private Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void square_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler( topLeftSquare_Click );
            //topRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler( topRightSquare_Click );
            //bottomLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler( bottomLeftSquare_Click );
            //bottomRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler( bottomRightSquare_Click );

            topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( centerSquare.Height / 2, centerSquare.Width / 2 );
            topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( centerSquare.Height / 2, centerSquare.Width / 2 );
            bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( centerSquare.Height / 2, centerSquare.Width / 2 );
            bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( centerSquare.Height / 2, centerSquare.Width / 2 );

            topLeftSquare.Location = new Point( 0, 0 );
            topRightSquare.Location = new Point( 50, 0 );
            bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point( 0, 50 );
            bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point( 50, 50 );

            topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

            this.Controls.Add( topLeftSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( topRightSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( bottomLeftSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( bottomRightSquare );

            centerSquare.Dispose();
        }

        private void topLeftSquare_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler( topLeftSquare_Click );
            //topRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler( topRightSquare_Click );
            //bottomLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler( bottomLeftSquare_Click );
            //bottomRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler( bottomRightSquare_Click );

            topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( topLeftSquare.Height / 2, topLeftSquare.Width / 2 );
            topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( topLeftSquare.Height / 2, topLeftSquare.Width / 2 );
            bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( topLeftSquare.Height / 2, topLeftSquare.Width / 2 );
            bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( topLeftSquare.Height / 2, topLeftSquare.Width / 2 );

            topLeftSquare.Location = new Point( 0, 0 );
            topRightSquare.Location = new Point( 10, 0 );
            bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point( 0, 10 );
            bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point( 10, 10 );

            topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

            this.Controls.Add( topLeftSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( topRightSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( bottomLeftSquare );
            this.Controls.Add( bottomRightSquare );

        }

        private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            centerSquare.Click += new EventHandler( square_Click );
            centerSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 50, 50 );
            centerSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add( centerSquare );
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I click on a square it doesn't split, instead all the buttons get smaller and smaller (which is the intended behavior but it was only meant for one square and it was expected to be sliced into 4 too).

Any help would be appreciated.

****************************** EDIT ******************************

Many thanks to Ninos answer, that solved the problem.
I did some cleaning, so here's the main result for those that are also looking for the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace divideSquare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random rnd = new Random();
        private int _initHeight = 500;
        private int _initWidth = 500;
        private Button centerSquare = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void setSquareLocation( Button[] squareArray, Button senderSquare, int newHeight, int newWidth )
        {
            squareArray[ 0 ].Location = new Point( senderSquare.Left, senderSquare.Top );
            squareArray[ 1 ].Location = new Point( senderSquare.Left + newHeight, senderSquare.Top );
            squareArray[ 2 ].Location = new Point( senderSquare.Left, senderSquare.Top + newWidth );
            squareArray[ 3 ].Location = new Point( senderSquare.Left + newHeight, senderSquare.Top + newWidth );
        }

        private void square_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            Button topLeftSquare = new Button();
            Button topRightSquare = new Button();
            Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
            Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();
            Button senderSquare = sender as Button;
            Button[] squareArray = { topLeftSquare, topRightSquare, bottomLeftSquare, bottomRightSquare };

            int newSquareHeight = senderSquare.Height / 2;
            int newSquareWidth = senderSquare.Width / 2;

            foreach (var square in squareArray ) {
                square.Click += new EventHandler( square_Click );
                square.Size = new Size( newSquareWidth, newSquareHeight );
                square.BackColor = Color.FromArgb( rnd.Next( 256 ), rnd.Next( 256 ), rnd.Next( 256 ) );
            }

            setSquareLocation( squareArray, senderSquare, newSquareHeight, newSquareWidth );

            foreach ( var square in squareArray ) {
                this.Controls.Add( square );
            }

            this.Controls.Remove( senderSquare );
        }

        private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            this.Width = _initWidth + 18;
            this.Height = _initHeight + 40;
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(_initWidth + 18, _initHeight + 40 );
            this.MinimumSize = new Size( _initWidth + 18, _initHeight + 40 );

            centerSquare.Click += new EventHandler( square_Click );
            centerSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(_initWidth, _initHeight );
            centerSquare.BackColor = Color.FromArgb( rnd.Next( 256 ), rnd.Next( 256 ), rnd.Next( 256 ) );
            this.Controls.Add( centerSquare );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to remember you have more squares each and every time.  But your code is altering the existing squares.. you need to remove the square you split, and replace ti with 4 new ones

Comment: I noticed, I was trying to do this with the minimal number of objects created, that's why I tried using the other squares. I guess I need to follow your hint, for every square clicked i need to create n+3 squares and dispose the original clicked.

Comment: Well you dont need to create n+3, just shrink the 1 you started and add 3 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on this...

First, i removed buttons declaration into `square_Click` method, because everytime you need to create new buttons, and your code just reuses buttons instantiated on form creation. That was your biggest issue with existing code.

Second, since clicking on every button does same code, i merged two methods (`square_Click` and `topLeftSquare_Click`) into one method.

Take a look:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button centerSquare = new Button();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button topLeftSquare = new Button();
        Button topRightSquare = new Button();
        Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
        Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();

        Button senderSquare = sender as Button;
        topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
        topRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
        bottomLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
        bottomRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);

        int newSquareHeight = senderSquare.Height / 2;
        int newSquareWidth = senderSquare.Width / 2;

        topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newSquareHeight, newSquareWidth);
        topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newSquareHeight, newSquareWidth);
        bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newSquareHeight, newSquareWidth);
        bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newSquareHeight, newSquareWidth);

        topLeftSquare.Location = new Point(senderSquare.Left, senderSquare.Top);
        topRightSquare.Location = new Point(senderSquare.Left + newSquareHeight, senderSquare.Top);
        bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point(senderSquare.Left, senderSquare.Top + newSquareWidth);
        bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point(senderSquare.Left + newSquareHeight, senderSquare.Top + newSquareWidth);

        topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
        topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
        bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
        bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

        this.Controls.Add(topLeftSquare);
        this.Controls.Add(topRightSquare);
        this.Controls.Add(bottomLeftSquare);
        this.Controls.Add(bottomRightSquare);

        this.Controls.Remove(senderSquare);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        centerSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
        centerSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        centerSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Controls.Add(centerSquare);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very nice. Didn't knew I could use sender like:

`Button senderSquare = sender as Button;`

I was trying to figure that out so I could use the button I cliked on the get the attributes.

Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and made some modifications. Please use the code below, it worked the way you need. Code is self explanatory. In case you need help on any line of code, please let me know. I hope it helps you

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button centerSquare = new Button();
        private Button topLeftSquare = new Button();
        private Button topRightSquare = new Button();
        private Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
        private Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Split(sender as Button);
            centerSquare.Dispose();
        }

        private void topLeftSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Split(sender as Button);
        }

        private void Split(Button source)
        {
            Button topRightSquare = new Button();
            Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
            Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();

            topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(topLeftSquare_Click);

            int width = source.Height / 2;

            topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width,width);
            topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, width);
            bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, width);
            bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, width);

            topLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            topRightSquare.Location = new Point(topLeftSquare.Width, 0);
            bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, topLeftSquare.Height);
            bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point(topLeftSquare.Width , topLeftSquare.Height );

            topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

            this.Controls.Add(topLeftSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(topRightSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(bottomLeftSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(bottomRightSquare);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            centerSquare.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
            centerSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
            centerSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add(centerSquare);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a hierarchy of squares.  See changes below.  I did not debug the code but just gave a basic solution to issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace divideSquare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChildSquare root = new ChildSquare();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        private void square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildSquare  oldButton = sender as ChildSquare;
            oldButton.topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(topLeftSquare_Click);
            //topRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(topRightSquare_Click);
            //bottomLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(bottomLeftSquare_Click);
            //bottomRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(bottomRightSquare_Click);

            oldButton.topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(oldButton.centerSquare.Height / 2, oldButton.centerSquare.Width / 2);
            oldButton.topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(oldButton.centerSquare.Height / 2, oldButton.centerSquare.Width / 2);
            oldButton.bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(oldButton.centerSquare.Height / 2, oldButton.centerSquare.Width / 2);
            oldButton.bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(oldButton.centerSquare.Height / 2, oldButton.centerSquare.Width / 2);

            oldButton.topLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            oldButton.topRightSquare.Location = new Point(50, 0);
            oldButton.bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, 50);
            oldButton.bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point(50, 50);

            oldButton.topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            oldButton.topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            oldButton.bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            oldButton.bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

            this.Controls.Add(oldButton.topLeftSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(oldButton.topRightSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(oldButton.bottomLeftSquare);
            this.Controls.Add(oldButton.bottomRightSquare);

            oldButton.centerSquare.Dispose();
        }

        private void topLeftSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildSquare childTopLeftSquare = sender as ChildSquare;
            childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(topLeftSquare_Click);
            //topRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(topRightSquare_Click);
            //bottomLeftSquare.Click += new EventHandler(bottomLeftSquare_Click);
            //bottomRightSquare.Click += new EventHandler(bottomRightSquare_Click);

            childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Height / 2, childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Width / 2);
            childTopLeftSquare.topRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Height / 2, childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Width / 2);
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomLeftSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Height / 2, childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Width / 2);
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomRightSquare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Height / 2, childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Width / 2);

            childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            childTopLeftSquare.topRightSquare.Location = new Point(10, 0);
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomLeftSquare.Location = new Point(0, 10);
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomRightSquare.Location = new Point(10, 10);

            childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            childTopLeftSquare.topRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomLeftSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;
            childTopLeftSquare.bottomRightSquare.BackColor = Color.Red;

            childTopLeftSquare.Controls.Add(childTopLeftSquare.topLeftSquare);
            childTopLeftSquare.Controls.Add(childTopLeftSquare.topRightSquare);
            childTopLeftSquare.Controls.Add(childTopLeftSquare.bottomLeftSquare);
            childTopLeftSquare.Controls.Add(childTopLeftSquare.bottomRightSquare);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            root.Click += new EventHandler(square_Click);
            root.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            root.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add(root);
        }
    }
    public class ChildSquare : Button
    {
        public Button centerSquare = new Button();
        public Button topLeftSquare = new Button();
        public Button topRightSquare = new Button();
        public Button bottomLeftSquare = new Button();
        public Button bottomRightSquare = new Button();

    }
}
```